# Adjusting nivo slider settings does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

Im trying to get nivo slider to work, but i keep getting a "syntax error" on the last lines line..... can anyone help me. I really just cant see whats wrong.

the error happens on the first:" }); " fourth line from the bottom

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'random',               // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    slices: 15,                     // For slice animations
    boxCols: 8,                     // For box animations
    boxRows: 4,                     // For box animations
    animSpeed: 500,                 // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime: 3000,                // How long each slide will show
    startSlide: 0,                  // Set starting Slide (0 index)
    directionNav: false,             // Next & Prev navigation
    controlNav: false,               // 1,2,3... navigation
    controlNavThumbs: false,        // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
    pauseOnHover: false,             // Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance: false,           // Force manual transitions
    prevText: 'Prev',               // Prev directionNav text
    nextText: 'Next',               // Next directionNav text
    randomStart: false,             // Start on a random slide
    beforeChange: function(){},     // Triggers before a slide transition
    afterChange: function(){},      // Triggers after a slide transition
    slideshowEnd: function(){},     // Triggers after all slides have been shown
    lastSlide: function(){},        // Triggers when last slide is shown
    afterLoad: function(){}         // Triggers when slider has loaded
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if this your problem or not, but you have a `<script>` tag inside of another `<script>` tag. Is this how your actual code is or is this just a copy-paste typo?

Comment: this is actually how it is

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using $(window).load(function(){...}); rather than $(document).ready(function(){...});?

You should do that and also you are going to get an error when you have a script tag within a script tag. It may work in firefox, but it won't in other browsers. So get rid of that extra script tag.